# How to make service and repository layer asynchronous in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am making a rest api. I want that rest api to be asynchronous. I have learn the completablefuture interface but I am facing problem to combine the completablefuture with repository and service. Please help me to solve this.
Should I use completablefuture only in repository or in both?

UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
@Async
CompletableFuture<List<User>> findByName(String name);
}
```

UserSerice:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<User>> find(String name) throws ExecutionException, 
InterruptedException {
    CompletableFuture<List<User>> userCompletableFuture = userRepository.findByName(name);
    return userCompletableFuture.get(); // I don't know what to do here
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't make your repo async, just your service, then wrap it in a completable future in the service.

Comment: and how to get the list of user from completablefuture?

Comment: What do you think `get` is for... Or use the `on***` methods to define behavior what you want to do when the future is complete or errors or ...

Comment: Ok thankyou and why should we not make repository async?

Comment: With this current sample you will endup spawning 3 threads (including the original caller) which is probably not what you intend to do.

Comment: Ok thankyou so much for helping me.
I was stuck for an hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242029/discussion-between-tameer-hussain-and-m-deinum).