# How to make asynchronous rest api in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am making an application in spring boot. I am using spring data and mysql. I want to make my service repository class to work asynchronous. I know about executor and competablefuture. But I don't know how to apply that knowledge in spring boot. Please help me.

Post Class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")

public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String subject;
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Comment> comments;

public Post(Long id, List<Comment> comments) }
```

Post Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post,Long> {

@Async
CompletableFuture<Post> findBySubject(String subject);
}
```

Post Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PostService {

@Autowired
private PostRepository postRepository;

@Async
public CompletableFuture<Post> find(String subject){
    CompletableFuture<Post> completableFuture = postRepository.findBySubject(subject);
    return completableFuture;
}
}
```

Post Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {

@Autowired
private PostService postService;

public Post get(@RequestParam String subject){
    try {
        Post post = postService.find("subject").get();
        return post;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question again, the answer is alread in the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71122184/how-to-make-service-and-repository-layer-asynchronous-in-spring-boot

Comment: unrelated: don't output a database object from your controller. Copy it into a dto with the same fields. in a year the db may change while the api should stay the same and you run into problems. 

this will also stop you from passing the dbo future straight to the controller.